# Scala classOf generic type in Kafka json deserializer

Tags: scala, jackson, apache-kafka, jackson-module-scala

I'm writing a kafka json deserializer in scala using Jackson but am having a problem providing jackson's `readValue()` method the class of a generic type. For example:

```
...
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

class JsonDeserializer[T] extends Deserializer[Option[T]] {

  val mapper = (new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper)
    .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .findAndRegisterModules()
    .asInstanceOf[ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper]

  def deserialize(topic: String, bytes: Array[Byte]): Option[T] = {
    Option(bytes) match {
      case Some(b) => Some(mapper.readValue(bytes, classOf[T]))
      case None => None
    }

  }

  def configure(configs: java.util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean) {}
  def close(): Unit = {}
}
```

Notice the `mapper.readValue(bytes, classOf[T])` in the `deserialize` method. Compilation fails with "class type required but T found".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic types in Java are erased at runtime so there's no way to recover the `Class` without passing it in explicitly.

Well, explicitly as far as Java is concerned. You can use an `(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])` or the shorthand `[T: ClassTag]` to (implicitly) obtain a `ClassTag` at construction time, which allows you to retrieve `Class` later on.

```
import scala.reflect._

class JsonDeserializer[T: ClassTag] extends Deserializer[Option[T]] {
  ...
    mapper.readValue(bytes, classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
```

Comment: I tried that actually but the context bound `[T: ClassTag]` seems to automatically change the primary constructor's no-arg signature which makes Kafka unable to instantiate it due to: *Could not instantiate class com.me.serialization.JsonDeserializer Does it have a public no-argument constructor?*

Comment: @novon Unfortunately, it's not possible. For any particular type `Foo` you can easily create a `class OptFooDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[Foo]` and use `OptFooDeserializer` though.